# How can I build amazon kinesis webrtc sdk in C on windows - missing header files

Tags: c++, windows, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm trying to build [`WebRTC SDK in C for Embedded Devices`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-c.html) on windows.
I have configured using CMake with `-DBUILD_DEPENDENCIES=0`, and have installed various libraries manually such as pthreads, usrsctp, libssl etc.
I don't have gstreamer installed, so I do get a message about not being able to configure one of the examples, but that is expected.

I'm running cmake from a "x64 native tools command prompt for vs 2019", hence the configuration below.

So after configuration I have a visual studio solution, which as far as I can tell should be able to build the examples.
However, the code uses an include file that is referencing non-existent files in the SDK. In particular, `Include.h` in `com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/webrtcclient/` begins with:

```
#include <com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/client/Include.h>
#include <com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/common/Include.h>
#include <com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/webrtcclient/NullableDefs.h>
#include <com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/webrtcclient/Stats.h>
```

but there is no `client` or `common` directory in `com/amazonaws/kinesis/video`. The `com` directory is in the repo directory `src\include`, which to me looks like the `video\client` dir should have been checked out if it exists, rather than built.

I also don't see any solution to build any kinesis libraries, but the examples seem to include a lot of the source files directly - so is this SDK supposed to build a library as well?

Have I missed a build step somewhere? Do I need to download/build the rest of the kinesis video stream stuff as well as the webrtc sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to build the other KVS libraries that the WebRTC implementation depends on.

You can find them in the [.gitmodules](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/blob/master/.gitmodules) of the project.

You can also see how they are built/configured in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L160-L165)

Comment: marking this as an answer, I have since figured the above out, but building on windows has been a right pain in the neck. 

Libwebsockets won't build as a dependency (but can be built standalone), yet there are other dependencies which must be built with this project (i.e. the other kvs libs - I can't seem to point at an external build of these, but I am a CMake noob)

My solution is to build libwebsockets and other libs separately, then remove their CMake files from CMake/dependencies and build the prjocet with dependencies, which brings in the kvs stuff